# What is the academic weighting of being a project associate on a cutting edge research project?

Tags: research-process, university

I am taking a little bit of a break from academics and I'm looking to do a job before I move on to doing my Masters. While I have a job lined up, it's going to start in 3 months. I was also offered a project associate job in the meanwhile. I am a BEng (bachelors) graduate, and I was wondering if this would actually help my chances at doing a good masters at a good university. Talk about your experiences at your university if you cannot generalize.

Comment: Be sure to check if your job offers educational reimbursement - for example, work for them for a period of time and they'll cover part if not all of your masters.

Comment: Are you talking about my future job offer or the project associate job that is more immediate

Comment: Your future job (the one starting in 3 months) - check with HR about their employee benefits relating to education.  It's relatively common in the U.S. for a company to cover part/all of an employee's education after working for a set period of time.  Not sure if that applies overseas though.

Comment: that's a very good idea. I am very interested in doing a masters and I guess I'll ask the company directly about this. I finished university in the UK, and currently am doing research/ work in India and planning on a masters in the states.

Answer (score 1):

Graduate admissions typically gives high weight to evidence of technical proficiency and research potential.  It sounds like working on this research project is likely to give you such experience.  If this can further turn into a strong recommendation letter from a well-reputed faculty member, then it will almost certainly be a significant boost to your chances.

Comment: I am defintiely looking to do something that will counter my performance on my Bachelor's degree. This could definitely boost my chances. Excellent suggestion about the recommendation letter!